# class design improvement - tweet - decoupling super global variables?

Tags: php

**Question:**

Should I decouple the SESSION variables, i.e. move them outside of the class...this was a suggestion from another POST.  I would like to extend this library to more general cases than just for my purposes..and I believe this is the next step here?

**Summary:**

This class sends "tweet" data to the client in the form of a custom markup language.

It is used in Ajax call and in previous post people have suggested not to echo the result..but this is my primary means of communicating with the server via Ajax responseText.

Also `<tw_p>` is used to denote a pass and is read by the client.  The markup looks like this.

field 1 | field 2 | field 3 | field 4 || field 1 | field 2 | field 3 | field 4 ||

It is called like this -

```
new tweet();
```

The client knows how render this into xhtml once it receives it.

```
/*tweet*/

class tweet extends post
  {
  function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $email=$_SESSION['email'];
    $flname=$_SESSION['name'];
    $message=$this->_protected_arr['f4b'];
    $time=time();
    database::query("INSERT INTO tw VALUES ('$time','$flname','$message','$email')");        
    $query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM tw ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 7");
    $b=0;
    $c='<tw_p>';
    while($a=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return))
      {  
      if($b==0)
        {
        $c = $c . $a['email'] . "|" .  $a['fname'] . "|" . $a['time'] . "|" . $time . "|" . $a['message'];
        }
      else
        {
        $c = $c . "||" . $a['email'] . "|" .  $a['fname'] . "|" . $a['time'] . "|" . $time . "|" . $a['message'];
        }
      $b++;
      }
    echo $c;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You've coded an [SQL Injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) into your application -- you have done no validation of the inputs `$flname` or `$email` but use them directly in a database query string. I suggest using [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid programming security flaws into your SQL queries. Decoupling this routine from your `$_SESSION` would be a good idea (I generally like to reduce reliance on "global variables"), but please fix your security flaws first.

Comment: Why don't you just use a global function?

Comment: the SESSION variables have already been sanitized to I need to do this again?

Comment: For your syntax consistency: http://codepad.org/8L6gsViS ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do if it was my code:

1. Remove logic from constructor, it is for initialization only. Thus remove all the business logic into separate method `doTheWork` (choose the meaningful name that explains what happens in the code)
2. Parametrize constructor with:

   - email
   - name
   - database instance (yes, I'd avoid static `database::query()` method)
3. Remove `echo $c;` in the end and replace it with `return $c;`
4. Remove the presentation logic from this class outside (the lines with `||` stuff)
5. Sanitize the data used in the query (thanks to [vzwick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961510/vzwick))

Comment: 5. (Actually, make that 1.!) Remove the SQL injection vulnerabilities

Comment: thanks....will return $c go into the responseText of my Ajax call?

Comment: no, so I would need a way to take $c and echo it in another functtion.  Is this the suggestion/answer?

Comment: @Chris Aaker: sure it will not, but each class is supposed to do one job. This class only performs some database work. Composing the response is the responsibility of another one

Comment: So basically all of my echo's through out my class hierarch need to be replaced with returns to a "composer" class which will do the echo?

Comment: @Chris Aaker: yes. Separate presentation layer from business logic layer.

Comment: @Chris Aaker: may be `MVC`? But it is not the only pattern that helps to structure your code.

Comment: @Chris Aaker: hehe, there is already xmarks ;-)